# Pushing value to sub-array

Tags: jquery, json, push

I'm having some issue with using .push(). I believe the problem is with how I'm defining my variables. Basically, the variable 'cache' keys do not correspond to data.system[] from JSON. I'm trying to push a number to an existing array using this (abbreviated version of code):

```
var cache = ['cpu','mem'];
function doAjax() {  /* toggled when ajax button pressed */
   $.getJSON( "ajax.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.system, function(i, key) {
              console.log(cache.i); /* undefined logged */
              cache.i.push(key.value); /*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined */
       });
   });
}
```

JSON:

```
{
 system: {
   cpu: {
      value: 1
   },
   mem: {
      value: 330
   }
}
}
```

Fiddle (I don't think I've setup the JSON data correctly though): http://jsfiddle.net/x9JaP/

Comment: I see no array in your json structure.

Comment: I left out the outside { }. The JSON works perfectly for the other areas of code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change this:

```
var cache = ['cpu','mem'];
```

for this:

```
var cache[] = {'cpu','mem'};
```

and this:

```
console.log(cache.i);
cache.i.push(key.value);
```

for this:

```
console.log(cache[i]);
cache.push(key.value);
```

You can have more luck.